# HTML5 YouTube embed for safari/chrome mac user the video starts playing in div with display none attribute

Tags: macos, html, youtube, embed

This is my first question, so your patience is much appreciated. I am having a weird issue with safari/chrome mac users only. This works superbly in IE7, IE8, Chrome, FF and safari(windows). Trying to determine and isolate the issue related to safari/chrome browsers since they start playing the embeded video inside hidden div immediately on page-load.

My company redesigned their homepage and I built it on our site recently. I am fairly new and this was my first solo webpage with JQuery slider, HTML5 etc. (I am unable to provide the link here).

Description of the page:

1. I have a slider in place which is using the auto-advance.js file to
   automate the rotation of images every 7 seconds.
2. One of the images belonging to this image list slider has a "play video"
   button. Below is the image map area which calls a javascript
   function on "play video" href click that "hides the image" and "displays the video div"

*Javascript function:*

```
    `function doStuff() {
    $('div#vid').css('display','inline');
    $('img.hid').css('display','none');
    }
```

`

*Here is the hidden div with HTML5 iframe youtube embed code:*

```
    `<div style="display:none;" id="vid">
    <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="770" height="430"        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cPoENdJx5DQ?       wmode=transparent&feature=player_embedded&autoplay=1&rel=0" frameborder="0"        allowfullscreen="false">
    </iframe>
    </div>
```

`
Everything works beautifully in windows but for mac users the video starts playing in the background (since the div is still hidden they hear music from the video). To fix the issue immediately I had to swtich off the autoplay option (here I edited it back to 1) on the site which has solved the issue temporarily.

I am trying to understand why chrome/safari mac browsers are autoplaying the video on pageload itself and not on href "play video" button click.

I have carried out detailed research and could only find this article on the issue : http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/CSS/Q_27722407.html, which makes me think that maybe this could be because of some code clash possibly? And if it is then why the browsers in windows are working perfectly?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It simply is built into the youtube swf to play if you have no attribute to say otherwise.

Comment: In windows the youtube video should also start playing that is actually a flaw in their case...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
function vidrun(){
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = 'code here for video';
    document.getElementById("the surrounding element's id").appendChild(span);
)
```

This will only add the video when you get to the time you want the video to automatically start playing instead of actually already loading the video and starting it.
All you will have to do to start the video playing when you get to that point is to call the `vidrun()` and done :]

Comment: Hello gabeDel, Thank you for a quick response. I tried this piece of code but the browser is throwing "document.getelementbyId("vid")" is null or not an object error. so far I have check in IE and FF and it is not working.

Comment: document.getelementbyid() is important that you capitolize the E in element the b in by and the i in Id other wise it will not work